# Приёмы архитектуры - конструктивные или конструкторские?

Tags: паронимы

> Вот уже сто лет как русскую историю архитектуры занимает вопрос:
>   возможно ли объяснить некие явления и конструктивные приёмы
>   древнерусской архитектуры влиянием балканской строительной практики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Приёмы** характеризуют *действия* конструк**торов**, поэтому предпочтительно *конструкторские*. *Конструктивные* относится к свойствам конструк**ции** (конструктивные особенности, отличия, признаки). И лишь в переносном смысле "конструктивные" характеризует *действия*, направленные на результат (построение воображаемой конструкции).

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее: конструктивные приемы

Можно утверждать, что значение чисто технического приема, позволяющего письменно фиксировать формулы модальной ритмики, полностью соответствует тому значению, которое имели **архитектурные конструктивные приемы,** используемые аббатом Сюжером при возведении им собора аббатства Сен-Дени и превратившиеся в фундаментальные принципы постройки всех великих готических соборов, воздвигнутых позднее.[Владимир Мартынов. Конец времени композиторов (2002)]

**КОНСТРУКТИВНЫЙ,**  1. к Конструкция (1 зн.). **К-ые особенности здания.**

**КОНСТРУКТОР,** - м. 1. Тот, кто конструирует что-л., создаёт конструкцию чего-л. К. самолётов. Инженер-конструктор  (руководитель проекта). Модельер-конструктор. Главный к.  (руководитель проекта). **<Конструкторский,**  **К-ое бюро.**

Answer (score 1):

Меня не убеждают доводы ни сторонников слова "конструкторские", ни предлагающих вариант "конструктивный". Конструкторский - связано с конструкторами (например,конструкторское бюро, где работают конструкторы). Конструктивный - это прилагательное давно используется в значении "конкретный, проработанный, основательный, аргументированный, обоснованный" (например, конструктивный диалог, конструктивное предложение, конструктивный подход к проблеме). В приведенном же вопросе речь идет о конструкции архитектурного сооружения, поэтому наиболее уместным я считаю слово "конструкционный"

Answer (score 0):

От смысла зависит.
Поскольку приемы *конструкторов* (методы разработки и изготовления, постройки) обычно постфактум не видны зрителю, а коструктивные как раз видны, то вернее всего здесь - **конструктивные**.